# Compare two list with out using linq for update History

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

Hi i'm working on a project written in c# webform and it requere loghistory of changes if some one updated the data i should be inserted to logs table but i need to capture which column or which field is being update.
so i think comparing 2 list the oldList before update and the list after update
if i have this class

```
public myClass class{
public string col1{get; set;}
public string col2{get; set;}
public string col3{get; set;}
}
```

and list like this with datas

```
List<myClass > old = new List<myClass >();
List<myClass > new = new List<myClass >();
```

how can i compire this 2 and get the column and the old and new data of the difference with out using Linq because the application is a existing and uses **.net 2.0 framework** so i belive Linq is not availavle yet in this.

I'm not requered to update the framwork for some reason.

Comment: I give you the `for` loop and `if` statement... *.Net Framework 2* (2005 complaint).. When you tried this, what wasn't working for you?

Comment: yes i can compare the data's how can i canture which column has the difference sorry im still newbie

Comment: A string, a list of strings?

Comment: `if(old[i].col1 != new[i].col1) Console.WriteLine("Col1 is diffrent")`

Comment: yes that will do im thinking of shorcut because i have many columns

Comment: usually, there is some logging system in the database engine, why not using that to your advantage ? for instance, in SQL Server, you could use Trigger to access `inserted` and `deleted` tables which would store the new and old values for the table, which it can be reused to for instance insert them in a permeant log table to track the changes, then you just use this table to view these changes in your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Implement IComparable interface in your class

```
public class myclass : IComparable<myclass>
        {
            public string col1 { get; set; }
            public string col2 { get; set; }
            public string col3 { get; set; }

            public int CompareTo(myclass obj)
            {
                return this.col1.CompareTo(obj.col1);
            }
        }
```

> Then sort your list and iterate through it

```
            oldlist.Sort();
            newlist.Sort();
            for (int i = 0; i < oldlist.Count; i++)
            {
                string oldcol1 = oldlist[i].col1;
                string newcol1 = newlist[i].col1;
            }
```